# Getting `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing host permission for the tab` in background script of firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

Here is my background script;

```
/**
 * CSS to hide everything on the page,
 */
const hidePage = `body > : {
    display: none;
  }`;


/**
 * When a tab is loaded, check if the plugin is on. If the plugin is on, check if the url matches the page.
 * If it does, block it
 */
browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    browser.storage.local.get("onOff")
        .then((result) => {
            if (Object.entries(result).length === 0 || !result.onOff.value) {
                return;
            }
            browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }).then((tabs) => {
                let tab = tabs[0];
                console.log(tab.url);
                browser.tabs.insertCSS({code: hidePage})
            }, console.error)
        });
});
```

and here is my `manifest.json`

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Beastify",
    "version": "1.0",
  
    "description": "Adds a browser action icon to the toolbar. Click the button to choose a beast. The active tab's body content is then replaced with a picture of the chosen beast. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples#beastify",
    "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify",
    "icons": {
      "48": "icons/beasts-48.png"
    },
  
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "activeTab",
      "storage"
    ],
  
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/beasts-32.png",
      "default_title": "BlockIt",
      "default_popup": "popup/blockit.html"
    },

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background_scripts/blocker.js"]
    },
  
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      "beasts/frog.jpg",
      "beasts/turtle.jpg",
      "beasts/snake.jpg"
    ]
  
  }
```

There is some superfluous stuff there because I am building my add-on from a [Firefox extension tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension).

The exact code that is causing the
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing host permission for the tab` is

`browser.tabs.insertCSS({code: hidePage})`

line 23 of `blocker.js`

I believe I do have the correct permissions to insert css from this background script, so I cannot figure out why this error is occurring.  I also tried to execute a content script instead of running the line above that is throwing the error, but that failed with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activeTab` works only when the user explicitly invokes your extension as described in the documentation for [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#activetab_permission) and [Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)). Evidently, its name is highly misleading: it should have been something like `activeTabWhenInvoked`.

In order to access any tab without prior interaction with your extension you'll have to add broad host permissions in manifest.json:

```json
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
```

Now there's no need for `activeTab`, but you may still want to keep `tabs` permission for Firefox older than 86, see the [note in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#api_permissions).

P.S. It's better to remove the listener altogether when `onOff` is false so the extension doesn't run in vain. You can do it by using a global named function for the onActivated listener and observing the changes to `onOff` via browser.storage.onChanged event.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you.